# How to hide fields based on user?

Tags: php, phpbb3

I'd like to hide some objects (e.g. `{postrow.POST_LIKERS_COUNT}`) when a user is the post owner.

```
<div style="float: right; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;" 
class="postlove">
<!-- IF (not S_USER_LOGGED_IN)  --><span class="plus-likes">+</span>
<span class="counter-likes" id="like_{postrow.POST_ID}">
{postrow.POST_LIKERS_COUNT}</span>
<!-- ELSEIF S_USER_LOGGED_IN -->
<span class="plus-likes">+</span>
<span class="counter-likes" id="like_{postrow.POST_ID}">
{postrow.POST_LIKERS_COUNT}</span>
<!-- IF DISABLE != 1 -->
<!-- IF !postrow.DISABLE -->
<a href="{postrow.POST_LIKE_URL}" data-ajax="toggle_love">
<!-- ENDIF -->
<!-- ENDIF --><span class="button-like {postrow.POST_LIKE_CLASS}" 
id="likeimg_{postrow.POST_ID}"></span>
<!-- IF !postrow.DISABLE -->
<!-- IF DISABLE != 1 -->
</a>
<!-- ENDIF -->
<!-- ENDIF -->
<!-- ENDIF -->
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 15px;">

<p>Liked: {postrow.POST_LIKERS}</p>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*If you want to hide first tag.*/
div :first-child{
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<div>
<span class="counter-likes" id="like_{postrow.POST_ID}">
First child</span>

<span class="counter-likes" id="like_{postrow.POST_ID}">
Second child</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That is not I want. I will try to explain it again. I got extension to phpbb3 "Love post" and I'dlike to hide button "like" to every post owner. for example I wrote 3 posts in one topic so I can't see on my posts button "like" - I can't give myself "like"